# Read S3 gzip file in a memory efficient way

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to import large Athena DB to S3 exports (gzipped) into Python. The piece of code below works fine and fast for smallish files but passed 100Mb+ I run into a memory saturation on my machine:

```py
s3 = boto_session.resource("s3")
obj = s3.Object(domain, gz_path)
with gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=obj.get()["Body"]) as f:
    data = [json.loads(ln) for ln in tqdm(f.read().decode('utf-8').split('\n')[:-1], desc='Loading from s3')]
```

The culprit seems to be `f.read()` which loads the entire file in one large string. I am unfamiliar with Gzip objects and my options in iterating line by line here (or streaming by bunch of lines). Or maybe there is an even better way of getting it done.

Edit:

I have changed my code for

```py
s3 = boto_session.resource("s3")
obj = s3.Object(domain, gz_path)
with gzip.open(obj.get()["Body"]) as f:
    data = [json.loads(line) for line in tqdm(f, desc='Loading from s3')]
```

More memory efficient for large files, but at the expense of a slow down on smaller files. Also the iteration has no estimated ending time, hence no progess bar.

Comment: Is your intention to keep all the data in memory? Because `data=` seems to be doing that. It possibly needs to keep two copies in memory -- one for `data` and one for `f.read()`. What is your actual end-goal? Do you really need _all_ the data loaded into a Python list?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein yeah in most cases I do want all the data to be stored in `data`. Downstream I do re-shape it into a pandas dataframe after a quick transform, so the end goal is more to have it inside a dataframe, if this matters.